# Comparing two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, rows, lookup

I have data with about 15 different columns and a total of 2400 rows.
The two columns I'm interested in: (Column C = Application Owner & Column D = Application Tester).  I'm trying to see which rows have the same name for both columns.

E.g.

Column C =
Mike
Bob
John
Bob
Adam

Column D =
Mike
Barry
Barry
Barry
Adam

So for this example I would like it to delete the contents of the three middle rows and only show me the first and fifth row because that is what I'm concerned with. Can anyone suggest a function of code or a function in Excel in which I can do this without actually having to go through all of them row by row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with something like `=C2=D2` copied down to suit, filter for FALSE in that column and delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

In a new Columns you can use `=if(C2=D2,"DELETE","")` then filter out this new column for `DELETE`  and delete the values from column `C` and `D` or the entire range